# How to avoid noise from light source while taking photo or video in iphone

Tags: video, iphone, photos, snapshot

I have iphone 13 pro with triple camera on it's rear.

whether it's video or photo there's always unwanted noise coming from light sources and it spoils the video and photos.

Please see the areas that's marked in red color.

[image]

Is there any setting in iPhone camera app or any tool to fix this issue ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because .....   Belongs in Ask Different (Apple forum)

Comment: clean your lens...

Comment: @John I'd argue that technically speaking that's a question about computer hardware. It's completely indifferent that it happens to be an iphone. So it's perfectly ok on SU

Comment: Or ask at https://photo.stackexchange.com/, specifically for photo

Comment: You're always going to get flare if you shoot directly into light. The pattern of the flare could be a) the lens design or b) dirt on the surface. The veiling flare [the foggy bit lower right] is caused by light from outside the field of view being reflected around inside the lens. You can shield that by holding your hand just out of shot, making a shadow on the lens. [If this gets migrated to photography I'll turn it into an answer.]

Answer (score 1):

This happens when the light is scattered on dirt (or rarely on small scratches) on your lens. Clean your lens, best with an antistatic cloth, or with a clean soft cloth.

Usually the dirt is grease or sweat from your fingers handling the phone. If you need something liquid for cleaning, make sure it's a product good for electronics (although often some spit works well enough).